# Extend UIView with new properties

Tags: ios, swift, properties, uikit

In my app I need to add to a bunch of `UIKit` objects some properties; my original thought was to create a subclass of each element I needed and create the properties inside the new class but I realized that this means to write a new class for each UI element type I'm using.

In my specific case, I wanna add to some different views, such as `UIImageView` and `UILabel`, two properties called `initial position` and `final position` of type `CGRect` to store the initial and final position in order to use it inside a method which translates this views.

Is there any way to accomplish this without creating lots of classes?

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated your question ([edit], don't post comments) with details about some specific examples of what you need and why.

Comment: @rmaddy I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
protocol Position {
    var initialPosition: Int { get set }
}
```

It is not possible to just declare properties in extensions, so you'd need to set your `get` and `set`. You can just associate a value:

```
private var initialPositionKey: UInt = 0
extension Position {
    var initialPosition: Int {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &initialPositionKey) as! Int
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &initialPositionKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you extend your `UIView` like this:

```
extension UIView: Position {}
```

And the following works:

```
var view = UIView()
view.initialPosition = 5
print (view.initialPosition) // 5
```

Comment: Can I just extend UiView with a protocol who defines two optional variables and then set them manually from each subview?

Comment: Sure, just set your property as `{ get set }`, extend UIView and set in each view.

Comment: Yeah could you edit it adding the things we talked down here?

Comment: You question is very low quality. Next time specify a better example,  like at least the type of the properties, or what one transformation would look like. This is the most general I could make it give the lack of detail.

Comment: If this does not work for you, please edit your original question giving more detail.

Comment: Can you explain me how the objc_getAssociatedObject function works?

Comment: Basically it associates a value with a given key, no hidden magic. Check out this article for more details: https://medium.com/@marcosantadev/stored-properties-in-swift-extensions-615d4c5a9a58 Feel free to open a new question about `objc_getAssociatedObject` if you still have doubts.